# Wikipedia API and JSON

Tags: javascript, xml, json, api, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to read the article text in the browser using Wikipedia API (to do more with php).

[Link to the Wikipedia article in xml](http://be.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&titles=%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8C&format=xml) //looks OK, you can read it if you know **Belarusian** language (utf-8?).

[Link to the Wikipedia article in json](http://be.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&titles=%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8C&format=json) //not good. The same article in json format but you can't read it if you don't know **unicode**. The pages in not displayed in utf-8 anymore. Several days ago I was able to read the text. The letter `ж` displayed as `ж` (like any other cyrillic), now only `u0436` is displayed.

What's the reason it has changed? Is that my browser settings or Wikipedia changed the json answer?

How to fix it so it is shown in utf-8?

Comment: Your JSON parser should decode that automatically.  If it doesn't, get a better parser.

Comment: What do you mean get a better parser? I use Google Chrome and the page displayed in a different way, not as several days ago. May be I need to add a special parameter to get the article in utf-8? Thank you.

Comment: @Haradzieniec: the API is not supposed to be read in the browser, but to be consumed by a robot. If you want to get the text in your browser, use the HTML view.

Comment: @Bergi I wrote a html-page that displays the Wikipedia article by name using ajax on my page. Several days ago it worked. Now it doesn't. I've tried to find what happened and now I see it returns the article in the unicode, not in utf-8. I'm trying to figure out what was changed and how to return it back. I use the same browser as several days ago, the same page and the same links. No javascript code was changed these days. 
Thank you.

Comment: Please show us the code on your HTML page that does the ajax. Somewhere there should be a JSON parser involved. Btw, [UTF8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) *is* Unicode - what you mean are escape sequences which are very valid in [JSON](http://json.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can downvote even more or even close this question.

However, in case my answer would help anyone, here is the solution. The problem was not changed Wikipedia API, but my Google Chrome settings.

`"-allow-file-access-from-files"` and `"-disable-web-security"` settings for the Google Chrome helped me. I used that settings the last time and I forgot to apply them today.